# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(Object,Throwable) in ParseCallback2

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to do a ParseQuery in my RecyclerAdapter class:

```
// Differentiate between feedItem views and nativeAds
    @Override
    public int getViewType(int position) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("NativeAd");
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "fYBeufqdOt");
        final int[] n =  new int[1];
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                n[0] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(object));
            }
        });

        int viewType = VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED;
        if ((position % n[0] == 0) && position > 0) {
            viewType = VIEW_TYPE_AD;
        }
        return viewType;
    }
```

I get the following error in my RecyclerAdapter class:

```
Error:(75, 54) error: <anonymous com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(Object,Throwable) in ParseCallback2
```

What is going on? Should I perform the query elsewhere? If so, where and how?

Comment: In plane English, you need to implement the method done(Object, Throwable) in your ParseCallback2 Class

Comment: I don't have a ParseCallback2 Class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to specify the generic type of the class GetCallback

```
  @Override
  public int getViewType(int position) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("NativeAd");
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "fYBeufqdOt");
    final int[] n =  new int[1];
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            n[0] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(object));
        }
    });

    int viewType = VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED;
    if ((position % n[0] == 0) && position > 0) {
        viewType = VIEW_TYPE_AD;
    }
    return viewType;
}
```

see the [doc](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/GetCallback.html)

For your second question, well it's really tricky

You have used a table of int to allow anonymous class (`GetCallback`) to update data in the outer scope.

However, this trick is not very good due to the synchronization issues, which is the case, because **the GetCallback class is used to run code after a ParseQuery is used to fetch a ParseObject in a background thread.**

So when the JVM check this condition `if ((position % n[0] == 0) && position > 0)` the value n[0] may has not yet been modified.

As a workaround you may add a condition to check if n[0] has been modified before continue running your code but it's really not the best solution

```
@Override
  public int getViewType(int position) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("NativeAd");
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "fYBeufqdOt");
    final int[] n =  new int[1];
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            n[0] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(object));
        }
    });
    // waiting ...
    while(n[0] == 0) Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);

    int viewType = VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED;
    if ((position % n[0] == 0) && position > 0) {
        viewType = VIEW_TYPE_AD;
    }
    return viewType;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, other than the ``java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero``. Weird, n[0] should equal 25.

Comment: could you be more specific about this exception (code, error message)

Comment: Fair enough. I appreciate your investigation either way. Guess I'll have to do more research to get this going more efficiently.

Comment: Good look if you find a better why to do it please feel free to share it